# Why /copy is not working in ILE module

Tags: sql, rpgle

Ok, so I am a little confused.  I have created a simple module with one procedure.  It works like a charm when the prototype and Data structure are included internally...

```
  ctl-opt option(*srcstmt:*nodebugio) nomain ;

     dcl-ds IIM ext end-ds;
     dcl-pr GetIIM LikeDS(IIM);
        *n char(35) options(*nopass) value ;
     end-pr ;


   dcl-proc GetIIM  export ;

     dcl-pi *n LikeDS(IIM);
        Item char(35) options(*nopass) value ;
     end-pi ;

     exec sql
       select * into :IIM
         from iim where iprod=:ITEM;

     return IIM   ;
   end-proc ;
```

But when I use /copy, the SQL compiler doesn't like the data-structure and gives me an error...

**Prototype**

```
 /if defined(GetIIM)
   dcl-ds IIM ext end-ds;

   dcl-pr GetIIM LikeDS(IIM);
      *n char(35) options(*nopass) value ;
   end-pr ;

     /endif
```

**Procedure**

```
 ctl-opt option(*srcstmt:*nodebugio) nomain ;
       /define GetIIM
       /copy JAGRACE/SANDBOX3,prototype
       /undefine GetIIM

     dcl-proc GetIIM  export ;

     dcl-pi *n LikeDS(IIM);
        Item char(35) options(*nopass) value ;
     end-pi ;

     exec sql
       select * into :IIM
         from iim where iprod=:ITEM;

     return IIM   ;
   end-proc ;
```

**Procedure**

So, what stupid thing am I doing now?  The error code is **SQL 0312 Variable IIM not defined or not usable.**

I thought that the /copy would basically put that code snippet into the source and compile.  I understand that the SQL precompiler is having an issue, but I am lost...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the RPG preprocessor options (RPGPPOPT) parameter of the Create SQL ILE RPG Object (CRTSQLRPGI) command.

The online help...

> RPG preprocessor options (RPGPPOPT)
>
> ```
> Specifies if the ILE RPG compiler will be called to preprocess the  
> source member before the SQL precompile is run.  Preprocessing the  
> SQL source member will allow some compiler directives to be handled 
> before the SQL precompile.  The preprocessed source will be placed  
> in file QSQLPRE in QTEMP.  This source will be used for the SQL     
> precompile.                                                        
>
> *NONE                                                              
>     The compiler is not called for preprocessing.                  
>
> *LVL1                                                              
>     The compiler is called for preprocessing to expand /COPY and   
>     handle the conditional compilation directives except the       
>     /INCLUDE directive.                                            
>
> *LVL2                                                              
>     The compiler will be called for preprocessing to expand /COPY  
>     and /INCLUDE and handle the conditional compilation directives.
> ```

Make sure you're not using *NONE.

Comment: AFAIK Make sure you use /include.  Seems to work for me.

Comment: @danny117 `/include` is ignored by default. You'd need `*LVL2`, whereas `/copy` works at `*LVL1` or `*LVL2`,

Comment: `/copy` works fine as long as you are not using `RPGPPOPT(*NONE)` which is the command default.